# Checking if item exist in java Set by O(1)

Tags: java, set

I am using a `Set` of items.

```
Set<Objects> myObjects
```

This `Set` may contains thousands items. It is important for me can check existence of an items in this `Set` by O(1).

I know that there is a `contains` methods for a `Set` but by what order it is working? Is it working by O(1)?

Also if it is not efficient, how can check the existence by O(1)?

Comment: `Set` is an interface

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HashSet.contains()` has an expected running time of `O(1)`

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) :

> **This class offers constant time performance for the basic operations (add, remove, contains and size)**, assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets. Iterating over this set requires time proportional to the sum of the HashSet instance's size (the number of elements) plus the "capacity" of the backing HashMap instance (the number of buckets). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is important.

Answer (score 1):

The `Set`-implementation [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is expected to find values by `O(1)`. However, this implies that the objects you are storing provides a [hashCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()).

In Java 8 you can provide a good and efficient hash by using the following code:

```
Objects.hash(value1, value2, value3);
```

If used properly the `contains`-method of `HashSet` should work as expected (that is really fast ;).